# Flutter how to save List<XFile>

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to save a list that I get from image picker. It contains images or videos. I want to save it locally and open it on another page in my app.

I have started with this code:

```
List<XFile>? _imageFileList;

final String path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().path;
final File newImage = await _imageFileList.copy('$path/image1.png');
```

But I think I need to do it in another way. Does anyone know how I can save the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

**To save media:**

```
List<XFile>? _imageFileList;

  _write(XFile media, String mediaIndex) async {
    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final File file = File('${directory.path}/media$mediaIndex.jpg');
    await file.writeAsBytes(await media.readAsBytes());
  }

  saveFiles() {
    int index = 0;
    _imageFileList?.forEach((x) {
      _write(x, index.toString());
      index++;
    });
  }
```

**And to load media:**

```
File loadedImage;
List<File> _imageFileList;

void loadFiles() async {
    directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    setState(() {
      final mediaFiles = io.Directory('$directory/')
          .listSync()
          .where((e) => e is File)
          .where((file) => file.path.split('/').last.startsWith('media'));
      Iterable<File> files = mediaFiles.whereType<File>();
      for (final file in files) {
        _imageFileList.add(file);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
The code you are giving me gives me errors. I have tried to fix your code like this:

```
  int index = 0;
  String path = '';
  _function(String path, XFile x) async {
    final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    path = directory.path;
    File c = File(path).createSync(); //File has to be created first
    c.writeAsBytesSync(await x.readAsBytes());
  }

  saveFiles() {
    int index = 0;
    _imageFileList?.forEach((x) {
      _function("$path/image$index.jpg", x);
      index++;
    });
  }
```

But it isn't working
[image]

Comment: Did it work now?if so please tick my answer

Comment: It gives me error: ” This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void.”

Comment: Please could you be specific. What expression exactly?

Comment: I have added an image

Comment: Use this instead ```File c = await new File(path).create();```

Comment: The error is gone. Should I use the images like this: Image.file(
            File("$path/image1.jpg"),
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ), ?

Comment: Wrap it with a ```Sizedbox```  and then give the sizedBox height : 100 & width: 100

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what do you want, I recently did it..

```
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  File? file;
  List<XFile>? photo = <XFile>[];
  List<XFile> itemImagesList = <XFile>[];

  Future pickPhotoFromGallery() async {
    photo = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
    if (photo != null) {
      itemImagesList = itemImagesList + photo!;
      photo!.clear();
    }
  }

  Future saveItemInfo() async {
    PickedFile? pickedFile;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemImagesList.length; i++) {
      file = File(itemImagesList[i].path);
      pickedFile = PickedFile(file!.path);
    }
  }
```